# Using jndi in spring with WAS?

Tags: spring, websphere, datasource, jndi

I want to use Server Managed connection pool in my web application,Now i'm using JdbcTemplate to get the connection.How to get the datasource from the WebSphere and use in my application.
I googled but got confused with JndiTemplate and JdbcTemplate..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good guide to Websphere + Spring can be found at [Using Spring and Hibernate with WebSphere Application Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html)